# rspamd statistic autolearn configuration

Tags: rspamd

I placed the sample configuration for autolearn from `/etc/rspamd/statistic.conf` in `/etc/rspamd/local.d/classifier-bayes.conf`:

```
autolearn {
  spam_threshold = 6.0;
  junk_threshold = 4.0;
  ham_threshold = -0.5;
  check_balance = true;
  min_balance = 0.9;
}
```

and restarted rspamd, but no SPAM/HAM appears to be learned. What am I missing?

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry – the configuration works, it just took a couple of minutes for results to become visible in the Rspamd web UI.